# RTSP using live555

Tags: ubuntu, rtsp, live555

I recently downloaded the packages for live555 to stream clips using rtsp.
I have no idea how to use it.
Please assist me. 
For Ubuntu

Thanks

Comment: Have a look to live555 documentation http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/#config-unix

Answer (score 3):

Though Question is quite old and I'm sure you might have gotten your way around it, I'm still posting this step by step guide for configuring live555 for linux, for those who might be facing the same problem. So here goes:

```
1)cd to the live555 folder.
2)user$ ./genMakefiles linux
3)user$ make
```

(This is assuming you have gcc/g++ set up in your linux distro and its path setup).

You can then simply use one of the test programs in testProgs folder to check whether its working.

I'm assuming you need to test a sample x264 file you have downloaded or made. To do so, the easiest way is (What I always suggest to beginners):

```
1)Copy the x264 file to live/testProgs folder.
2)Rename it to test.264 (testH264VideoStreamer by default is set to stream a file named test).
3)go to terminal and type ./testH264VideoStreamer 
4)Copy the rtsp link (rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8554/abcd) to your vlc player to stream.
5) Further you can check the QoS parameters and stream profile by downloading openRTSP and use openRTSP -Q rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8554/abcd to view these parameters.
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I am getting below error. $ vlc rtsp://192.168.0.121:8554/testStream
VLC media player 3.0.3 Vetinari (revision 3.0.3-1-0-gc2bb759264)
[00005568c971a570] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Created new TCP socket 36 for connection
[h264 @ 0x7f53dc079540] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
Invalid UE golomb code
[h264 @ 0x7f53dc079540] pps_id 3199971767 out of range
[00007f53dc04cc00] avcodec decoder error: cannot start codec (h264)
[00007f53dc04cc00] main decoder error: Codec `h264' (H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)) is not supported

Comment: I can play that test.264 file directly from vlc player.

Answer (score 3):

1. Ensure for the appropriate compiler.

$ sudo apt-get install build-essential

2. Verify that your system don't have live555 libraries.

$ sudo apt-get remove liblivemedia-dev

3. Download and Install the libraries.

$ cd $HOME

$ wget http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/public/live555-latest.tar.gz

$ tar xvf live555-latest.tar.gz

$ cd live

$ ./genMakefiles linux

$ make

$ sudo cp -r $HOME/live /usr/lib

$ make clean